# How to let the browser handle download generated file with DataTables and TableTools

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, datatables, tabletools

using [this](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/TableTools/index.html) demo and all other demos of TableTools, I noticed that the downloaded file is not present in the browser's download window.

TableTools seem to bypass it and directly save it on the filesystem.

I looked for solutions but I found none. It's not even mentioned..

Is there a way to customise this feature?

Edit: I tried on OS X Mavericks both Firefox 25.0, Chrome 31.0.1650.48. 
On win7 64bit it's the same for Firefox 25.0, Chrome 30.0.1599.101 m, IE10.

Linuxatico

Comment: What browser? It works very well here. You set the default filename by the `sFileName`-settings, BTW.

Comment: Edited the question, anyway you confirm that after the download you have the downloaded file listed in the browser's download window? Which browser do you use and on what platform?

Comment: file like "TableTools example.csv" downloaded, after being asked about the filename. I am using chrome / ubuntu, but it works in all other browsers also, and on other OS. I know this for a fact, since I am using tabletools myself in several projects.

Comment: I am too able to download it after viewing the dialog asking the name and position, but after this I cannot see this same file in the download queue browser's window. This is my problem